# Correcting hijacked search in Chrome from "resultdns.com"?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, search, rootkit, hijack

*Potentially unnecessary background: I was a Sloppy Internet User today and downloaded an unsafe file without realizing my virus-protection software was offline. I noticed suspicious behavior from my browser and desktop, so I immediately culled the offending file, killed the most immediately suspicious processes and reactivated my antivirus protection; a quick scan caught several rootkits (among other miscellaneous problems), and I'm doing a thorough scan now. I do another thorough scan whenever I reboot.*

Now: I primarily use Google Chrome on Windows XP, and my search bar is set up to search Google by default. At the moment, attempting to use the search bar defaults to a Google look-alike, "resultdns.com". However, Chrome's settings report that Google is still the default search, so obviously my searches are being hijacked in some way.

Maybe I'm being premature in trying to fix this before my scans are finished, but if I can fix it now, I'd like to do so. How should I go about liberating my captive search bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that:

Control Panel -> Programs -> uninstall "Result Dns"

And make sure you thoroughly scan for additional spyware etc. etc. :D "resultdns" sounds very suspicious to me after a google search on it.